# How to execute flink job remotely when the flink job jar is bulky

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have flink server running on Kubernetes cluster. I have a job jar which is bulky due to product and third party dependencies. 
I run it via 
ExecutionEnvironment env = ExecutionEnvironment.createRemoteEnvironment(host, port, jar);
The jar size is around 130 MB after optimization. 
I want to invoke the remoteExecution without jar upload so that the upload does not happen everytime when the job needs to be executed. Is there a way to upload the jar once and call it remotely without mentioning the jar (in java)?

Answer (score 0):

You could deploy [a per job cluster on Kubernetes](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.7/ops/deployment/kubernetes.html#flink-job-cluster-on-kubernetes). This will submit your user code jar along with the Flink binaries to your Kubernetes cluster. The downside is that you cannot change the job afterwards without restarting the Flink cluster.